# get first and last value of a groupby object in laravel 5 and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a table called income.

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | employee_id | date                | gross  | income | credit | comission | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 | 2016-03-30 19:21:09 | 100.00 |  29.00 |  11.00 |     60.00 | 2016-03-31 19:21:46 | 2016-03-31 19:21:46 |
|  2 |           1 | 2016-03-31 19:24:44 | 110.00 |  43.00 |   1.00 |     60.00 | 2016-03-31 19:24:56 | 2016-03-31 19:24:56 |
|  3 |           2 | 2016-03-31 21:44:09 |  77.00 |  30.80 |   0.00 |     60.00 | 2016-03-31 21:44:19 | 2016-03-31 21:44:19 |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

what i want to do is query these and group it by `employee_id` and i want the date it started and date it end.  What i got is

```
$records = Income::whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])
                ->groupBy('employee_id')
                ->selectRaw('store_incomes.* , sum(gross) as total_gross , sum(income) as total_income, sum(credit) as total_credit')
                ->get();
```

This always return the first date for that employee.  For example, `employee_id 1` always return the date of `2016-03-30 19:21:09`.  What i want is to get the first and last date for each `employee_id`, so `employee id 1` would have start date of `2016-30-30` and end date of `2016-03-31`.  Is there a way to do this without messy manual code?

For the current code my output is :

```
[
{"id":"1","employee_id":"1","date":"2016-03-30 19:21:09","gross":"100.00","income":"29.00","credit":"11.00","comission":"60.00","created_at":"2016-03-31 19:21:46","updated_at":"2016-03-31 19:21:46","total_gross":"210.00","total_income":"72.00","total_credit":"12.00"},
{"id":"3","employee_id":"2","date":"2016-03-31 21:44:09","gross":"77.00","income":"30.80","credit":"0.00","comission":"60.00","created_at":"2016-03-31 21:44:19","updated_at":"2016-03-31 21:44:19","total_gross":"77.00","total_income":"30.80","total_credit":"0.00"}
]
```

My expected output is to include 2 more values (`start_date` and `end_date`):

```
[
{"id":"1","employee_id":"1","start_date":"2016-03-30 19:21:09", "end_date":"2016-03-31 19:24:44"},
{"id":"3","employee_id":"2","start_date":"2016-03-31 21:44:09", "end_date":"2016-03-31 21:44:09"}
]
```

Comment: Show us your expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I've edited to include my desired output.  Just wondering if i can achieve that in selectRaw?

Comment: Do you only want dates or you want other information as well?  Your aggregations might not make sense with two dates.

Comment: because i may have say 3 employee id, and say i want to show the record from feb to april.  When i query, i want my result to group by each employee, how much each employee make between the start and end date.  However, not all employee start at the same date and end at the same date.  So i have to display the start and end date of each employee.

Comment: What is the purpose of `whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])` then, if you are taking the min and max date for each employee?

Comment: so say $start is 2016-03-01 and $end is 2016-03-31.  in this period, employee 1 start working from 2016-03-15 and quit at 2016-03-20.So i want to show that the start and end date of employee 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107915/discussion-between-dat-tran-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw MySQL query you want is something along these lines:

```
SELECT MIN(date) AS start_date, MAX(date) AS end_date, store_incomes.*,
    SUM(gross) AS total_gross , SUM(income) AS total_income, SUM(credit) AS total_credit
FROM income
GROUP BY employee_id
```

To do this in Laravel, just add `MIN()` and `MAX()` to your raw query:

```
$records = DB::Income
               ->selectRaw('store_incomes.* , min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date, sum(gross) as total_gross , sum(income) as total_income, sum(credit) as total_credit')
               ->groupBy('employee_id')
               ->get();
```